# Displaying Image in Repeater Control Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have developed a Real Estate website in which user can buy and sell their properties. I used Repeater control to display the images and other related fields. The problem is that one Property can have multiple images what i want is to show the first image of the property in Repeater Control is it possible to choose the first picture of the product from the database?

Note: I am using VB.NET

[Product View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ieb2K.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, etc. Database diagram, a little bit of code

Comment: Sound like you should optimize your query, the Repeater just displays all the records it receives.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the above solution using SQL Sub-Query?